# Application.Evaluate with multiplication and range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem writing a line of code using Application.Evaluate. I have a table with data that looks like this:

```
00:01  Mark  1  0  3  5 
00:02  Mark  2  8  7  1 
00:05  Mark  8  1  4  3 
00:08  Mark  9  5  5  5 
00:10  Mark  7  8  9  7
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is multiply the first column (00:01 until 00:10) with the 3rd column, and place the result in another sheet, then the same with the 4th column and so on. The idea is for excel to do something like this:

((00:01 * 1) + (00:02 * 2) + (00:05 * 8) + (00:08 * 9) + (00:10 * 7))

In the following code OCT is the worksheet with the table, and Month is the worksheet where the results should be placed and MonthSkipRow and MonthRow are used to find the correct Row in Month:

```
Dim OCTStartRow as Range
Dim OCTEndRow as Range
Dim MonthSkipRow as Range
Dim MonthRow as Range
dim i as Long, j as Long, x as Long, y as Long, w as Long

i = 3
j = 2

Do Until i > 33

If Not OCT.Columns(2).Find("Mark", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then

    Set OCTStartRow = OCT.Columns(2).Find("Mark", lookat:=xlWhole)
    x = OCTStartRow.Row

    Set OCTEndRow = OCT.Columns(2).Find("Mark", lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    y = OCTEndRow.Row

    Set MonthSkipRow = Month.Columns(1).Find("Total Duration Outbound (hrs)", lookat:=xlWhole)
    z = MonthSkipRow.Row

    Set MonthRow = Month.Columns(1).Find("Mark", lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("A" & z))
    w = MonthRow.Row

    Month.Cells(w, j).Value = Application.Evaluate( _
        (OCT.Range(Cells(x, i), Cells(y, i)) & "*" & _
        (OCT.Range("A" & x) & ("A" & y))))
    End if
    j = j + 1
    i = i + 1

Loop
```

My problem is the last line of code, I keep getting the error message "Run-time error "13": Type mismatch". My guess is that the line is baddly written. I am hoping someone knows how to write it properly. I hope it all makes sense.

Comment: at first glance this looks wrong: `OCT.Range("A" & x) & ("A" & y))`. Try `OCT.Range(OCT.Range("A" & x),OCT.Range("A" & y))`

Comment: Also, where's your `End If`?

Comment: Why even use evaluate for this?

Comment: Per Tim Williams comment, Sumproduct is the function you want, either as a worksheet formula or in code.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I tried it with you addition, but had the same end results.

Comment: @BruceWayne My bad, I forgot to add it, I've fixed that.

Comment: @Rory I used evaluate since I've used it before, that's pretty much it. I have never used Sumproduct before (not in VBA at least), could you provide an example of how it would work with this problem?

Comment: `Month.Cells(w, j).Value = Application.Sumproduct( _
        OCT.Range(Cells(x, i), Cells(y, i)), _
        OCT.Range("A" & x, "A" & y))`

Comment: @Rory Fantastic. I tried it with that one and it worked perfectly. Thank you